# Java - Formatting Strings in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, formatting

I have an ArrayList that contains elements in the following format:

```
1. 11111 "Top Secret Twenty One - Janet Evanovich" $8.99 1 0% $8.99
```

What would be the best way to format each element in the ArrayList to make it look as follows:

```
11111, "Top Secret Twenty One - Janet Evanovich", 8.99, 1, 0.0, 8.99
```

I'm basically looping through the ArrayList and placing it in an output file. How can I format it in this loop?

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(file);

for(int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){

    bw.append(items.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: You want to remove `1.` ? and all the special symbols

Comment: how from $8.99 you ended up this 10.95?

Comment: How come your ArrayList contain elements with different data type? Is type of your ArrayList Object? Since when $ and % are datatype?

Comment: Each element of the ArrayList is a string of characters like the element shown above. I have it set as ArrayList<String>.

Comment: So it is not clear what you want AT ALL?

Comment: @VinayVeluri I need to remove the beginning number along with the $ and % symbols at the least.

Comment: It seems that you're probably not using ArrayList appropriately

Comment: @CocoNess can you explain why for my learning goal plz?

Answer (score 0):

You should use POJO in your list. If you must do it like that I hope this can help you:

```
        String s1 = "1. 11111 \"Top Secret Twenty One - Janet Evanovich\" $8.99 1 0% $8.99";
        String first = s1.substring(3);
        first = first.substring(0, first.indexOf(" "));
        String title = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("\""), s1.lastIndexOf("\"")+1);
        String rest = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("\"")).replaceAll("\\$", "").replaceAll("%", "");
        String result = first+" ,"+title+rest.replaceAll(" ", ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not regex?

```
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\s(\\d+)\\s\\\"(.+)\\\"\\s\\$(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)%\\s\\$(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("1. 11111 \"Top Secret Twenty One - Janet Evanovich\" $8.99 1 0% $8.99");
    if(matcher.find()){
        String[] tab = {matcher.group(1), '\"'+matcher.group(2)+'\"', matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4), ""+(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(5))/100), matcher.group(6)};
        System.out.println(String.join(", ",tab));
    }
```